# Extracting URL from text field in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

This seems like it should be easy but I'm spinning my wheels -

I need to write an SSRS expression that extracts a URL from a text field.  The text field may or may not contain a URL and the assumption is that there will never be more than one.  Also, the URL is not fixed and can vary between records, but will always start with http.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
IIF
(
    Not(Fields!ActivityNote.Value Like "*http*"),
    "",
    IIF
    (
        Fields!ActivityNote.Value Like "*http* ",
        Mid
        (
            Fields!ActivityNote.Value,
            InStr(Fields!ActivityNote.Value,"http"),
            InStr(Fields!ActivityNote.Value," ")-InStr(Fields!ActivityNote.Value,"http") --I believe that this line is the problem
        ),
        Mid
        (
            Fields!ActivityNote.Value,
            InStr(Fields!ActivityNote.Value,"http"),
            Len(Fields!ActivityNote.Value)-InStr(Fields!ActivityNote.Value,"http")+1
        )
    )
)
```

Essentially there are two places the URL can appear - at the end of the text or anywhere else.  If at the end, it's easy - just use the Mid function starting at the location of http and use Len to find the end of the string.  My issue is when the URL is not at the end - I'm having trouble identifying the location of the first space that occurs after the URL (right now I'm assuming a space is the only character that can appear after the URL in the text field, though this may eventually prove to be a bad assumption).  Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: can you not do this at the data source level? Do you use SQL for your back end? You would get much better and (possibly) reliable results that way! and for starters like "*http* won't work

Comment: Harry, I agree about the right way to do this, but I'm being asked to do it at the report level as a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in SSRS but it's messy. This code should work as long as the field contains http. If no url is in the field it will return an error.

```
= LEFT(
    MID(Fields!ActivityNote.Value, InStr(LCASE(Fields!ActivityNote.Value), "http")),
    Instr(MID(Fields!ActivityNote.Value, InStr(LCASE(Fields!ActivityNote.Value), "http")) + " ", " ") -1
    )
```

To complete this you will have to test each start of the expression to check for the existence of 'http' and make this check case insensitive, it will get messy..

---

**However** 
This would be much easier written as a function, either in SSRS but ideally you should do this on your database server.

Here's a quick function to extract the url from a string (assuming SQL Server)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnExtractURL (@s nvarchar(1000)) RETURNS nvarchar(1000) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @url nvarchar(1000) =''
    SET @s = ISNULL(@s,'') + ' ' -- handle null and always add a spcae on the end of the string to search so we don't have to check for it

    IF @s LIKE '%http%'
        BEGIN
            SET @url = SUBSTRING(@s, 
                                CHARINDEX('http', @s),
                                CHARINDEX(' ', @s, CHARINDEX('http', @s)) - CHARINDEX('http', @s)
                                )
        END

    RETURN @url
END
```

If we test it with some sample data

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(i int IDENTITY(1,1), url nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO @t (url) VALUES
('No URL here'),
('Points to our favourite site http://www.stackoverflow.com/'),
('Note much use for https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football at the moment'),
(NULL),
('')

SELECT 
    *
    , dbo.fnExtractURL(url)
FROM @t
```

we get the following results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This expression got the job done:

```
SPLIT(
    MID(
         REPLACE(
                  LCASE(Fields!ActivityNote.Value), 
                  CHR(10), 
                  " "
                ),
         IIF(
              Fields!ActivityNote.Value Like "*http*",
              INSTR(
                     REPLACE(
                              LCASE(Fields!ActivityNote.Value), 
                              CHR(10), 
                              " "
                             ),
                     "http"
                   ),
              1000
             ),
          1000
        ),
     " "
).GetValue(0)
```

Thanks for the help.